# When should another AD domain be created purely to reduce replication traffic

Tags: active-directory, network-design

I'm going over some hypothetical AD design scenarios for learning purposes.

Lets say I have one domain and two physical locations, sites and DCs. The sites are connected via a limited bandwidth WAN link (say 1mbps or like a single T1).

Now lets say I have thousands of users in each location. Replication traffic would be reduced if I had 2 domains instead of just 2 sites. But how many thousands of users would it take for this to be an efficient solution (assuming there is still only one IT dept and there are no political\operational needs for separation)?

I'm really just trying to come up with a scenario where you would want to create an additional domain only for the purposes of reducing replication traffic. Does this every happen IRL? Microsoft recommends a single AD domain whenever possible due to the added administrative overhead. Also not sure if my scenario would hold up due to the fact that a company with thousands of users probably has enough dough to just buy a fatter pipe and keep the single domain infrastructure.

edit: Sorry for the hypothetical question I probably should have just asked "would I ever need another domain if I don't have any political or security boundaries to worry about". I think what Ryan said about the Infrastructure Master falling into obsolescence is interesting. Although, the old "why isn't domain X in Contoso's multi-domain forest getting updated" is one less freebie exam question.

Comment: `I'm really just trying to come up with a scenario where you would want to create an additional domain only for the purposes of reducing replication traffic` - I'm thinking never.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, @red888, but you *do* know that purely hypothetical questions are somewhat frowned-on here, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primarily opinion based? I think there are too many factors and variables to really be able to definitively answer this objectively. And the answers would typically be anecdote-based.

No it almost never happens IRL.

Yes you should stick to a single domain forest unless you have a very good reason for not doing so.

10-15 years ago, it was fashionable to create an "empty forest root domain" that did essentially nothing, and then a subdomain of that forest root that actually held your employee user accounts, etc. However, I do not see that design in new implementations much any more, and when I do see that design it's a legacy environment that the admins wish hadn't been designed that way. Microsoft has also stopped recommending this design. This design was not intended to control replication bandwidth, but my point is, single-domain forests are the way of the future.

Honestly, I would not be surprised if the Infrastructure Master FSMO eventually fades away as a vestigial role in Active Directory...  like a pinky finger.

Yes replication traffic between different domains will typically be less than intra-domain replication. But by exactly how much depends on many, many variables.

Exactly how much replication traffic you generate is based on not only how many users and computers you have, but how often updates are being made to those objects. Especially in recent versions of Active Directory which use linked value replication, AD replication is *usually* among the lowest bandwidth consumers on your network.

Comment: it was fashionable to create an "empty forest root domain" ... Microsoft has also stopped recommending this design.."- I remember that, but didn't realize Microsoft stopped recommending it that's good to know.

Comment: @red888 Here is a design guide and a bandwidth matrix that I think covers your question quite specifically. For instance, it talks about 100,000 users in a forest with **28.8k modems** for network links! AD generally uses very little bandwidth for day to day operations. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732201(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @red888 I also just want to be clear that when I say "MS stopped recommending this," sure they will still tell you how to deploy a dedicated forest root domain in their documentation, and there are still political and business and organizational reasons that would dictate that you *must* build a dedicated forest root domain. I'm just citing what I have heard from the mouths of MS consultants, speakers at conferences, what I personally see in the field, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would say "Never." Assuming they were in the same forest, you would still have GC replication, and I'm sure other things. You can always tune your replication between sites to reduce the impact of replication.

The only scenario I could think of is if they were entirely disconnected, which obviously would be a rare occurrence in real life (lab, air-gap for security) and you would design for that.